# EventEmitter is continuously emitting the value

Tags: angular, forms, angular-directive

I'm trying to create a directive which shows a loading bar when user is typing and submits the input when the user has stopped typing.

```js
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoSave]',
})
export class AutoSaveDirective {
  @Input() formGroup!: FormGroup;

  private _state!: 'loading' | 'synced' | 'modified' | 'error';

  @Output() stateChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() formError = new EventEmitter<string>();

  private formSub!: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.preloadData();
    this.autoSave();
  }

  preloadData() {
    this.formGroup.markAsPristine();
    // this.state = 'synced';
  }

  // Autosaves form changes
  autoSave() {
    console.log('inside changes');
    this.formSub = this.formGroup.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        tap(change => {
          this.state = 'modified';
        }),
        debounceTime(2000),
        tap(change => {
          if (this.formGroup.valid && this._state === 'modified') {
            // this.onSubmit.emit();
            this.state = 'synced';
          }
        }),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  set state(val: any) {
    this._state = val;
    this.stateChange.emit(val);
     if (val === 'synced') {
       this.onSubmit.emit();
     }
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.formSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

```js
  changeState(event: string) {
    this.changeHandler.emit(event);
     if (event === 'synced') { // condition
       this.submit(); 
     }
  }
```

If I remove the above if condition everything is working fine. But I have to call the submit function when the values are synced and the user has stopped typing.

```html
    <form
      [formGroup]="situationFormGroup"
      appAutoSave
      (stateChange)="changeState($event)"
    >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your *autosave* method you have written *tap* operator inside *pipe* function as follows:

```
tap(change => {
    this.state = 'modified';
})
```

What above code does is for each *valueChanges* in *FormGroup* it would set *state*, which will emit a *stateChange* event. Hence for each change *EventEmitter* is emitting values (Refer the code in setter of your *state*)

To avoid that do something like these:

```
tap(change => {
    if(this._state!=='modified'){ 
        this.state = 'modified';
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start from cutting this directive responsibility.

> It is doing to much ..  'loading' | 'synced' | 'modified' | 'error'.
>   I would suggest creating 3 directives:
>   (Keep it SOLID)

- LoadingDirective
- ErrorDirective
- TypingDirective

And than in TypingDirective you would only display that loader on beginning of `form.valueChanges` and than in `tap(this.onSubmit.emit(...))` after `debounceTime(2000)`.

Comment: What is meaning of `!` in `@Input() formGroup!:`?

Comment: it means it can't be undefined